# I have upgraded libsecp256k1 to latest master but I'm having issues to link it properly now. How can I resolve this?

Tags: python, compiling, secp256k1, error

I have upgraded libsecp256k1 to the latest master but I'm having issues to link it properly now. What is the problem and how might I resolve it?

The error message is:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
secp256k1/src/ecmult_impl.h:324: undefined reference to `secp256k1_pre_g'
```

I'm able to build libsecp256k1 as a standalone, this error happens when I try to link it to MicroPython.

This was asked by Guest6320 on [IRC](https://gnusha.org/secp256k1/2022-09-25.log).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered on [IRC](https://gnusha.org/secp256k1/2022-09-25.log).

The error was resolved by compiling the `secp256k1.c` file, the `precomputed_ecmult.c` file and the `precomputed_ecmult_gen.c` file into object files and linking against that. You used to only need to compile the single file `secp256k1.c` into an object file.

Alternatively if that doesn't resolve your problem you could try `make clean` and `git clean -dfx`. Otherwise the bindings you are linking to MicroPython may need to be updated.